Which is more nucleophilic: acetamide or aniline?
Which compound will be more nucleophilic, knowing that the electron pair will be more delocalized in the ring for aniline? On the contrary, for the acetamide the electron pair will only be delocalized between two atoms, which in my opinion makes the electron pair more available.
But I am also thinking that the aromatic ring donates electron density to the amine group, which might make it more nucleophilic.

In acetamide nitrogen atom is much less basic and nucleophilic... But you're not asking about just nitrogen atoms at the moment - either you narrow it down or consider nucleophilicity of other atoms.
